# how to construct code for popupmenu to call webactivity

Tags: android

i am new to android ...i developing app in this i create a popup menu and it has the some menu ....i would like to operate that menu with webactivty ...

i have html file by using popup menu i call that file...

i tried a lot

```
package cse.svu;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class campus_facilities extends MainActivity {

MediaPlayer mp;
Button b1, b2, b3, b4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.campus_facilities);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.campus1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.campus2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.campus3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.campus4);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(campus_facilities.this, b2);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.campus1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, webviewactivity.class).putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/campus/campus_library.html"));
            mp.start();
            break;
        case R.id.campus2:
   /*in this area what i need to write a code ...please add popup menu and their options to go to         webactivity to call html file like above case*/

                mp.start();
                break;
        case R.id.campus3:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, webviewactivity.class).putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/mission.html"));
                    mp.start();
                    break;
        case R.id.campus4:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, webviewactivity.class).putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/academic_excellence.html"));
                    mp.start();
                    break;
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    campus_facilities.this.finish();
}
```

}

popup_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/physcial_health"
    android:title="@string/physcial_health"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/physcial_gym"
    android:title="@string/physcial_gym"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/physcial_ncc"
    android:title="@string/physcial_ncc"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/physcial_stadium"
    android:title="@string/physcial_stadium"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/physcial_computer"
    android:title="@string/physcial_computer"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />


</menu>
```

manefest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cse.svu" >

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="cse.svu.splashscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="cse.svu.MainActivity"
        android:label="SVU"/>
    <activity android:name="cse.svu.contact"
        android:label="@string/contact"
        android:parentActivityName="cse.svu.MainActivity"  />
    <activity android:name="cse.svu.about_svu"
        android:label="@string/about_svu"
        android:parentActivityName=".about_svu"/>
    <activity android:name=".academic_excellence"
        android:label="@string/academic"
        android:parentActivityName=".academic_excellence"/>
    <activity android:name=".adminstration"
        android:label="@string/admin"
        android:parentActivityName=".adminstration"/>
    <activity android:name=".campus_facilities"
        android:label="@string/campus"
        android:parentActivityName=".campus_facilities"/>
    <activity android:name=".researchandpublication"
        android:label="@string/research"
        android:parentActivityName=".researchandpublication"/>
    <activity android:name=".webviewactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".about_svu"/>
    <activity android:name=".webview2"
        android:label="adminstartion"
        android:parentActivityName=".adminstration"/>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: What's you are getting when menu button is pressed or on the actionbar?

Comment: i need to open popup and it has somr action to perform open html pages in web activity